# How to make two range price input have space between each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, javascript-objects

hey guys I'm creating a Slider Price input
and I have two ranges one from the left side and the right side, they both are connected to each other

but they touch each other, how I can create limited space between them at least 50$
so the right does not pass the left and the left not pass the right
and to not merge?

```js
(function() {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.range-slider');

  if (!parent) {
    return;
  }

  const rangeS = parent.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]'),
    numberS = parent.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');

  rangeS.forEach((el) => {
    el.oninput = () => {
      let slide1 = parseFloat(rangeS[0].value),
        slide2 = parseFloat(rangeS[1].value);

      if (slide1 > slide2) {
        [slide1, slide2] = [slide2, slide1];
      }

      numberS[0].value = slide1;
      numberS[1].value = slide2;
    }
  });

  numberS.forEach((el) => {
    el.oninput = () => {
      let number1 = parseFloat(numberS[0].value),
        number2 = parseFloat(numberS[1].value);

      if (number1 > number2) {
        let tmp = number1;
        numberS[0].value = number2;
        numberS[1].value = tmp;
      }

      rangeS[0].value = number1;
      rangeS[1].value = number2;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 6em;
}

.range-slider svg,
.range-slider input[type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

input[type="number"]:invalid,
input[type="number"]:out-of-range {
  border: 2px solid #ff6347;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #2497e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  border: 1px solid #2497e3;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #a1d0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #2497e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  border: 1px solid #2497e3;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #a1d0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower,
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #2497e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  border: 1px solid #2497e3;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #a1d0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider">
  <span>from <input type="number" value="3000" min="0" max="100000" step="500"> to <input type="number" value="75000" min="0" max="100000" step="500"></span>
  <input value="3000" min="0" max="100000" step="500" type="range">
  <input value="50000" min="0" max="100000" step="500" type="range">
  <svg width="100%" height="24">
        <line x1="4" y1="0" x2="480" y2="0" stroke="#444" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="1 28"></line>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Offtopic... `document.querySelector` why limiting yourself to only one element in the DOM instead of creating a reusable component for *N* elements?

Comment: Also, stop misusing `on*` handlers like `oninput`. `on` handlers should be only used when creating brand new elements from in-memory. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead

Comment: if we are already pasting codepen snippets, why not take one that works already? https://codepen.io/MarioD/pen/WwXbgr

Comment: @exside because i want to make it RTL AND LTR jquery is only LTR

Comment: how is jquery related to RTL/LTR support? it's just logic, jquery doesn't define logic... but regardless i meant the above example as one that i have found to satisfy your requirements, so maybe you want to analyze that code instead of the example you posted?